# HTTP post in node js using forEach

Tags: node.js, post, foreach

I have a program that has to loop through an array and then post it and getback the data. for example.

The array is as below.

```
var fruits = ["apple","banana","mango","orange","carrot"]
```

I have an url as below.

```
var url ="https://www.fruitsdatabase.com/fruitNames"
```

and I want to post the data. And I'm using the below code.

```
for (var i in fruits) {
    var uhri = "https://www.fruitsdatabase.com/fruitNames";
    var options = {
        uri: uhri,
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "type": "fruits",
            "params": {
                "name": fruits[i]
            }
        }
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (body) {
                console.log(fruits[i] + "\t" + body);
            } else {
                console.log('sorry no results found');
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Wow this is an err");
        }
    });

}
```

When I'm trying to print this the result that I get looks like this.

```
apple [object, object]
banana [object, object]
mango [object, object]
orange [object, object]
carrot [object, object]
```

when I change `console.log(fruits[i] + "\t" + body);` to `console.log(body);`

```
    {
      Table1:
       [ { Name: 'apple',
           type: 'fruit',
           color: 'green',
         }
       ] 
    }
    {
      Table1:
       [ { Name: 'banana',
           type: 'fruit',
           color: 'yellow',
         }
       ] 
    }
    {
      Table1:
       [ { Name: 'mango',
           type: 'fruit',
           color: 'yellow',
         }
       ] 
    } 
    {
      Table1:
       [ { Name: 'orange',
           type: 'fruit',
           color: 'orange',
         }
       ] 
    }
    {}
```

since carrot is not a fruit, It should return a `{}` and in my above code instead of printing `carrot [object, object]`, it should print `carrot sorry no results found`. please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are doing request and get the callback inside for loop!

#### What is the problem ?

`for` loop will not wait for the `request` function to finish and call the callback , so you want to create another function , and send your `i` and both `fruits[i]` and callback arguments `(error, response, body)` will not be matched , and that is why you get that unexpected behaviour.

#### Solution

You can do a lot of solutions

1 - Create additional function to handle this :

```
function sendRequest(options){ // additonal function
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (body) {
                console.log(options.json.params.name + "\t" + body);
            } else {
                console.log('sorry no results found');
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Wow this is an err");
        }
    });
}

for (var i in fruits) {
    var uhri = "https://www.fruitsdatabase.com/fruitNames";
    var options = {
        uri: uhri,
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "type": "fruits",
            "params": {
                "name": fruits[i]
            }
        }
    };    
    sendRequest(options)
}
```

2 - Use [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module to call series of functions created by `Array.protorype.map()` using [`async.parallel`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel).

```
var async = require('async')

var fruitsFuncs = fruits.map(function(fruit){
    return function(fn){
        var uhri = "https://www.fruitsdatabase.com/fruitNames";
        var options = {
            uri: uhri,
            method: 'POST',
            json: {
                "type": "fruits",
                "params": {
                    "name": fruit
                }
            }
        }
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                if (body) {
                    console.log(fruit + "\t" + body);
                } else {
                    console.log('sorry no results found');
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Wow this is an err");
            }
            fn(error,body);
        });
    }
})

async.parallel(fruitsFuncs,function(err,results){
    console.log('Finished All')
});
```

Comment: Hi @Ezzat, sorry for the delayed response, this is also giving me the same result as of mine. there is no change